# Removing event listener can't see class function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an event listener to listen for Escape press, at which point my modal will close; however for some reason I am receiving an error that the close function call cannot be made.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.closeModalFunc is not a function at checkEscape
```

My class:

```
checkEscape(pressed) {
    if (pressed.key === 'Escape') {
        this.closeModal();
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.checkEscape);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.checkEscape);
}

closeModal () {
    // code to close modal
}
```

I found however that if I change `checkEscape` into a functional const, this problem goes away and everything works as intended.

```
checkEscape = pressed => { /** the same innards */ };
```

Of course I am happy that I can get this to work, however I would like to understand why this happened...

Comment: value of `this` is causing the problem. Since `this` inside arrow functions is the same as in the enclosing scope and in your case, enclosing scope is that of the component, so the problem goes away. You could use an arrow function or use `.bind()` to bind the value of `this` in `checkEscape`

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `.bind()`. Could you show me where I would bind to?

Comment: @physicsboy looks like your question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class components require you to do the super fun binding in the constructor, e.g.,

`this.checkEscape = this.checkEscape.bind(this);`

Arrow functions bind to the class auto-magically.

If that doesn't make you want to use functional components with hooks, I don't know what will. :D

Comment: Ah that clears things up for me, thanks.
I think, given now that I can see how it works both ways... I will go the arrow route as it's less code and I don't have to introduce a new constructor (Y)

Comment: @physicsboy `.bind()` is not a constructor. You can look it up on MDN for details.